# How to copy text with syntax highlighting?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, cut-copy-paste

Want a simple way, like notepad++ plugin: `NppExport` - `Export to RTF`, to copy selected text with syntax highlighting.

Notepad++, NppExport, Export to RTF example:

1. Select text
   [image]
   [image]
2. Copy RTF
   [image]
3. Paste with syntax highlighting
   [image]

Comment: You should explain what you want assuming nobody knows it beforehand. Specifically, tell us what `NppExport` does.

Answer (score 13):

It's a bit roundabout, but one way to achieve this with built-in tools is to use the `:TOhtml` command to create an HTML file that contains the highlighted text, open that file in a browser, and then copy from there.

`:TOhtml` takes a range, so you can use this method to "copy" the highlighted contents of a visual selection.

See `:help :TOhtml` and `:help 2html` for details.

Comment: Yes, I tried :TOhtml. It needs to save to another other file, open browser and copy. It will also convert the line number if it's enabled and if paste to outlook, line break gets wrong. I want to directly copy from vim.

Answer (score 4):

I found an email discussion about the same topic: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/convert-syntax-highlighted-text-to-RTF-td1177362.html

They also suggest `:TOhtml` and also an alternative plugin to convert to html. And then they suggest [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) to convert html → rtf.

And also found a vim plugin that claims to export to rtf (OS X only): https://github.com/zerowidth/vim-copy-as-rtf

It has been forked for Windows and Linux support too: https://github.com/adah1972/vim-copy-as-rtf

Answer (score 3):

I'm not on windows, but @root described in his answer, that you can copy formatted HTML to clipboard with the command `scb -as` (that's what I understood).

The following just collects @roots steps in a function. Put the following in your `vimrc`:

```
function! CopyFormatted(line1, line2)
    execute a:line1 . "," . a:line2 . "TOhtml"
    %yank *
    !start /min powershell -noprofile "gcb | scb -as"
    bwipeout!
endfunction

command! -range=% HtmlClip silent call CopyFormatted(<line1>,<line2>)
```

Then restart Vim and execute:

```
:HtmlClip
```

Comment: What are `a:line1` and `a:line2`? Does this pass particular lines from a file as input to the function?

Comment: @root Yes. Default is 1 and last line number. If you visually select a few lines, then its that line number range.

Comment: I must be missing something. I've put the function in my `_vimrc` and reloaded gvim. After, I open a document that has syntax highlighting, I run `:command! -range=% HtmlClip silent call CopyFormatted(<line1>,<line2>)`, and nothing happens. No change if I remove `silent`.

Comment: @root See update. The `:command...` also belongs into `vimrc`. You then have to run `:HtmlClip`.

Comment: Nice, this works. The only change is you must replace the single quotes with double quotes around the Powershell input (`"gcb | scb -as"`). The only drawback I see with this is also present in my solution, in that you must wait several seconds for PS to load before it can process the input. I was hoping `-noprofile` would help but my machine incurs a 1-3 sec load time.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following in gVim on Windows 10:

Record a macro that does the following:

1. `:TOhtml`
2. `ggVG` (select all)
3. `"*y` (yank to system clipboard)
4. `:q!` (close the TOhtml file)
5. `:!start /min powershell -noprofile "gcb | scb -as"` Start a minimized instance of Powershell that runs a shorthand equivallent of `Get-Clipboard | Set-Clipboard -AsHtml)`

After running this macro and allowing Powershell to complete, I can then paste directly into Outlook 2016.

Comment: Could you test the command I proposed in my answer? Maybe this is useful for you. I have no Windows machine available to test.

Comment: Nothing happens when I run that command. There are no messages and there is nothing sent to my system clipboard nor vim registers. I'll need to do some research on executing Powershell from within gvim.

Comment: I've updated my post.